# Normal subgroup of General linear group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What is the list of all normal subgroups of  general linear group $GL_n(q)$?  (n*n invertible matrix on finite field with $q$ elements)

It is well known $SL_n(q)$ and subgroups of $Z(GL_n(q))$ are normal.

Comment: All subgroups  of $Z$ are normal and all subgroups containing ${\rm SL}_n(q)$ are normal. That covers everything except for $(n,q)=(2,2),(2,3)$.

Comment: @ Professor Holt. Thanks. I saw the following theorem due to Kantor: If $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(n, q)$ containing a Singer cycle, then
$G \rhd  GL(n/s, q^s)$ for some s, embedded naturally in $GL(n, q)$. Can't this theorem bring a new type of normal subgroup?

Comment: @Professor Holt. This is the paper I mentioned "William M. Kantor. Linear groups containing a singer cycle. Journal of Algebra,
62:232-234, 1980.  Where is my fault?

Comment: I am sorry, your statement of the result of Kantor was correct. But that does not imply the existence of any other types of normal subgroups of  ${\rm GL}(n.q)$. If you choose the subgroup $G = {\rm GL}(n,q)$, then Kantor's result is true with $s=1$.